# Javascript Outline

Tags: javascript, documentation-generation, outline-view

For the documentation of a JavaScript project, the outline of a script file is needed, similar to these examples from [Eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fcoutline.htm) or [Oxygen](http://oxygenxml.com/doc/ug-author/topics/outline-view-JavaScript.html).

I only need the 'tree' structure of a JavaScript file, not a complete documentation.
Is there any parser, that outputs this outline tree in any format like JSON or XML? I think there is something out there, but actually i couldn't find it.

Here an example.

```
var someVar = "test";
function Test()
{

    this.value = false;

    this.main = function()
    {
        // do something
    };

}
```

the outline in JSON

```
[
  {
    line:1,
    type:'var',
    name:'someVar'
  },
  {
    line:2,
    type:'function',
    name:'Test',
    inner:[
       {
          line:5,
          type:var,
          name:'value'
       },
       {
         line:7,
         type:'function',
         name:'main'
       }
    ]
  }
]
```

Maybe unusal, but that's what needed.

Greetz!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Esprima](http://esprima.org/) might be a good pick. See also "[JavaScript Parsers and Extensions](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/List-of-languages-that-compile-to-JS)".

Comment: http://esprima.org/demo/parse.html

Nice! That's what is needed! Will here publish an example implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to JS documentation, try: http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer.
Is there a way in JsDoc to get only the outline information, not an complete documentation?

Comment: http://www.kajabity.com/2012/02/how-i-introduced-jsdoc-into-a-javascript-project-and-found-my-eclipse-outline/